# Как замерить время выполнения CRUD операций в MongoDB?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, explain

Не могу понять, как замерить время выполнения таких методов как insert, delete, update. Для метода find неплохо подходит метод explain. Для остальных же не могу понять. На оф. сайте написано, что метод explain можно использовать для delete, update, find и других, которых меня пока не интересуют. Но при вызове в mongosh возвращает ошибку

```
TypeError: db.users.dele ... 22")}).explain is not a function
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же только через профилировщик можно посмотреть?